# filesharing from 2 computers.

Tags: java, string, file-upload, jfilechooser, file-sharing

Well, I have this program, the download option is working fine. I can access the other computer and download the file from it to my desktop, but the upload is a problem. When I choose the file, the program tries to get the file from the other computer and not mine so the path is wrong. Is there somehow I can use JFileChooser (as I do in download) and put in my computer name or IP address? Before I started to try the access to another computer I did make it work with JFilChooser, but the path messes it up now. Some tips or tricks?

```
public void upload(String username) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException{

try {
            System.out.println(getProperty);
            String lol = "/hei/hei.txt";
            String ServerDirectory=("//" + "JOAKIM-PC"+ "/Users/Public/Server/"); 
            byte[] filedata = cf.downloadFile2(getProperty + lol);
            File file = new File(getProperty + lol); 
            BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream 
                    (new FileOutputStream(ServerDirectory + file.getName())); 
            output.write(filedata,0,filedata.length);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("FileServer exception: "+ e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void download(String username) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException{                           
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("//" + "JOAKIM-PC" + "/Users/Joakim/Server/");
        chooser.setFileView(new FileView() {
            @Override
            public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
                return (f.isDirectory() && f.getName().equals("Server")); 
            }
        });
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        } try {
            String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String clientDirectory = getProperty + "/desktop/";
            byte[] filedata = cf.downloadFile(selectedFile); 
            System.out.println("Byte[] fildata: " + selectedFile);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            System.out.println("fileName: " + fileName);
            BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(clientDirectory + file.getName()));
            output.write(filedata, 0, filedata.length);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("FileServer exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *`System.out.println(getProperty);`*  You have an attribute named `getProperty`?!?  Is there a `getGetProperty()` to get it and a `setGetProperty()` to set it?  That must become *very* confusing.

Comment: String getProperty = System.getProperty("user.home");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to use on your `upload` method this code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("./hei/");
int returnval = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
String ServerDirectory=("//" + "JOAKIM-PC"+ "/Users/Public/Server/"); 
if(returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

   try{
           byte[] filedata = cf.downloadFile2(file.getAbsolutePath());  
           BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream 
                    (new FileOutputStream(ServerDirectory + file.getName())); 
            output.write(filedata,0,filedata.length);
            output.flush();
            output.close();

   }
   catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Is it right for you?